# Change Font Size of Help Text in Apex

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I need to change Font Size of `Page Items Help Text` in Oracle Apex. How could I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Apex item help usually (maybe always?) has a class of "instructiontext".  So you can define attributes for this using CSS.  If you have a CSS script you can add an entry to it like this:

```
.instructiontext {color: red; font-size: 300%}
```

Otherwise you could simply add some inline CSS in the page template header like this:

```
<html lang="&BROWSER_LANGUAGE." xmlns:htmldb="http://htmldb.oracle.com">
<head>
<title>#TITLE#</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="#IMAGE_PREFIX#themes/theme_20/theme_3_1.css" type="text/css" />
<!--[if IE]><link rel="stylesheet" href="#IMAGE_PREFIX#themes/theme_20/ie.css" type="text/css" /><![endif]-->
#HEAD#
<!-- Add this -->
    <style type="text/css">
    .instructiontext {color: red; font-size: 300%}
    </style>
<!-- End of my CSS -->
</head>
<body #ONLOAD#>#FORM_OPEN#
```

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I know this is a seriously old post I'm digging up, but this post is what I ended up at, while searching for "instructiontext".

Anyway, I have new information. Tony's solution still works in APEX 5.0, but somewhere since between then and APEX 19.2, things got changed by Oracle. It appears that nolonger is the class "instructiontext" being applied, but instead the class "apex-help-dialog".

So, if you extend the CSS-definition like so:

```
.instructiontext, .apex-help-dialog {color: red; font-size: 300%}
```

it will work in both versions. This should prove convenient while transitioning your application from say, APEX 5.0 to APEX 19.2, like we are doing.

Hopefully this will be of some use to anyone.